# src/caffe/parallel.cpp:70:1: error: ‘Params’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, caffe

This is not the first time I compiled caffe, but I still have problems that I can't solve. The caffe version I used is https://github.com/chuanqi305/ssd, the compiled version is GPU, I successfully compiled and run on my computer ( Ubuntu 16.04 GTX1080TI*1 cuda9.0) , but in the school server (Ubuntu 14.04 Tesla k80*2+Tesla k40*2 cuda8.0), the same code, the same configuration, but the compilation failed。The error occurred in the code compilation phase rather than the link phase, but the code itself is definitely no problem, because it has been compiled successfully on another computer, I don't know if it is because of my gcc/g++ version.

I tried to compile the parallel.cpp file myself using the g++ command. When I don't specify the header file path, the same error will occur, but in the Makefile, the location of the header file has been added.

The error message is below:

```
SGM@user-SMBIOS-implementations-newer-thandmidecode-Super-Server:~/ssd-ssd$ sudo make all
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/parallel.cpp
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:70:1: error: ‘Params’ does not name a type
 Params<Dtype>::Params(shared_ptr<Solver<Dtype> > root_solver)
 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:77:1: error: ‘GPUParams’ does not name a type
 GPUParams<Dtype>::GPUParams(shared_ptr<Solver<Dtype> > root_solver, int device)
 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:102:1: error: ‘GPUParams’ does not name a type
 GPUParams<Dtype>::~GPUParams() {
 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:110:15: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void GPUParams<Dtype>::configure(Solver<Dtype>* solver) const {
               ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:117:6: error: ‘DevicePair’ has not been declared
 void DevicePair::compute(const vector<int> devices, vector<DevicePair>* pairs) {
      ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:117:60: error: ‘DevicePair’ was not declared in this scope
 void DevicePair::compute(const vector<int> devices, vector<DevicePair>* pairs) {
                                                            ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:117:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 void DevicePair::compute(const vector<int> devices, vector<DevicePair>* pairs) {
                                                                      ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:117:70: error: template argument 2 is invalid
src/caffe/parallel.cpp: In function ‘void caffe::compute(std::vector<int>, int*)’:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:133:20: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
             pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[j]));
                    ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:133:67: error: ‘DevicePair’ was not declared in this scope
             pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[j]));
                                                                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:157:18: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
           pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[j]));
                  ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:157:65: error: ‘DevicePair’ was not declared in this scope
           pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[j]));
                                                                 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:175:14: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
       pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[i + 1]));
              ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:175:65: error: ‘DevicePair’ was not declared in this scope
       pairs->push_back(DevicePair(remaining[i], remaining[i + 1]));
                                                                 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:185:10: error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   pairs->insert(pairs->begin(), DevicePair(-1, remaining[0]));
          ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:185:24: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   pairs->insert(pairs->begin(), DevicePair(-1, remaining[0]));
                        ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:185:60: error: ‘DevicePair’ was not declared in this scope
   pairs->insert(pairs->begin(), DevicePair(-1, remaining[0]));
                                                            ^
In file included from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:4:0:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:187:16: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   CHECK(pairs->size() == devices.size());
                ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:188:30: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   for (int i = 0; i < pairs->size(); ++i) {
                              ^
In file included from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:4:0:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:189:21: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
     CHECK((*pairs)[i].parent() != (*pairs)[i].device());
                     ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:189:45: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
     CHECK((*pairs)[i].parent() != (*pairs)[i].device());
                                             ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:190:36: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘* pairs’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     for (int j = i + 1; j < pairs->size(); ++j) {
                                    ^
In file included from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:4:0:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:191:23: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
       CHECK((*pairs)[i].device() != (*pairs)[j].device());
                       ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:191:47: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
       CHECK((*pairs)[i].device() != (*pairs)[j].device());
                                               ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp: At global scope:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:202:1: error: ‘P2PSync’ does not name a type
 P2PSync<Dtype>::P2PSync(shared_ptr<Solver<Dtype> > root_solver,
 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:249:1: error: ‘P2PSync’ does not name a type
 P2PSync<Dtype>::~P2PSync() {
 ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:271:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void P2PSync<Dtype>::InternalThreadEntry() {
             ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:287:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void P2PSync<Dtype>::on_start() {
             ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:325:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void P2PSync<Dtype>::on_gradients_ready() {
             ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:383:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void P2PSync<Dtype>::Prepare(const vector<int>& gpus,
             ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:421:13: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void P2PSync<Dtype>::Run(const vector<int>& gpus) {
             ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/caffe/blob.hpp:8:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/caffe/caffe.hpp:7,
                 from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:12:
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:439:19: error: ‘Params’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(Params);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:439:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::Params’
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:439:19: error: ‘Params’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(Params);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:439:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::Params’
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:440:19: error: ‘GPUParams’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(GPUParams);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:440:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::GPUParams’
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:440:19: error: ‘GPUParams’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(GPUParams);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:440:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::GPUParams’
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:441:19: error: ‘P2PSync’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(P2PSync);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:441:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::P2PSync’
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:441:19: error: ‘P2PSync’ is not a class template
 INSTANTIATE_CLASS(P2PSync);
                   ^
src/caffe/parallel.cpp:441:19: error: explicit instantiation of non-template type ‘caffe::P2PSync’
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o] Error 1
```

Makefile.config

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the lines after *_35 for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
# BLAS := atlas
BLAS := open
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
#PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
#       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
ANACONDA_HOME := /home/SGM/anaconda3
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /home/SGM/anaconda3/include \
        /home/SGM/anaconda3/include/python3.6m \
        /home/SGM/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include


# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.6m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /home/SGM/anaconda3/include/python3.6m \
                 /home/SGM/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include


# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/local/hdf5/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/hdf5/lib /home/SGM/anaconda3/lib/

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

Comment: have you edited the makefile.config (can you share it)? and have you done a <code>make clean</code> between attempts?

Comment: I did this before compiling, I will put the Makefile and Makefile.config on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the environment，have you edit the path in Makefile.config?
Please make the python path correct and make sure cudnn is installed，if you want to compile with cuDNN.
Not very clear with your issue, try comment `USE_CUDNN := 1`

Comment: I forgot to modify the Makefile.